# Is there a way of finding out what a bazaar update would do

Tags: bazaar

Is theere a way of finding out what changes a bzr update will do without actually doing it.
Specifially I would like to have a bit of warning if there is going to be a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly that I'm aware of, that's what `bzr revert` is for.  However, there is a common way to structure your local branches to help.  I use one local branch that mirrors the central branch, then I branch off of that for my work.  When I'm ready to "check in," I update my local mirror branch, which always succeeds without conflicts because I haven't changed my working copy of that branch.  Then I merge my feature branch into my local mirror branch, then push my local mirror branch to the central repository.

The advantage of this setup in your case is you could use `bzr merge --preview` or `bzr diff` to see the changes if you don't want to actually try the merge.  I personally prefer just to revert the merge until the conflicts are fixed either upstream or in my local feature branch.

Comment: +1 for `bzr merge --preview`, you can use `bzr merge --preview :bound` if you have a heavyweight checkout (bound branch).

Comment: Thanks Karl. Don't quite follow what you mean by "that's what bzr revert is for"

Comment: Just that it's not that big a deal to undo a conflicting merge if you're not ready to deal with it yet.